# How to set file permissions for root in OS X / Terminal?

Tags: apache, permissions, terminal, virtualhost, sudo

I'm having issues with getting Apache working with my virtualhosts, and I've narrowed it down to the fact that I'm adding manually-created virtual hosts (vs. the others which are created by a python script). When I run:

```
ls -l
```

I get this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root      wheel   772 May 10 17:53 host1.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root      wheel   766 May 10 17:53 host2.com
-rw-r--r--@ 1 myname    wheel   914 Mar 28 14:24 host3.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root      wheel  3897 May 10 17:53 host4.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root      wheel  5240 May 10 17:53 host5.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root      wheel  4037 May 10 17:53 host6.com
```

I'm not sure what the "@" refers to, but that manually-created file my username as the owner instead of root. When I view the file info in OS X (Finder), I see that permissions for most of the files show "system" has Read & Write access, but my manually-created vh file shows that I (my username) has Read & Write access.

Can someone tell me how to set the permissions for "system" or "root" in Terminal? I do have superuser access.

Comment: In osx `root` is displayed as `system` in the _Get Info_ dialogue. Ex `sudo chown root /foo.txt` will be listed as `system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ indicates that there are extended attributes. You can use the command xattr to have a look at them 
You can set the owner with chown

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution (and answered my side-question about the extended attributes as well).

Answer (score 9):

You can change the ownership of a file in terminal by using

```
sudo chown owner:group filepath
```

Or in your case

```
sudo chown root:wheel filepath
```

Additionally, you can change the permissions of a file by using `chmod`